Find the measure of the set $\{x : f(x) \geq 0\}$.

Let $f$ be defined on $[0,1]$ by $f(0) = 0$, $f(x) = x \sin
(\frac{1}{x})$ for $x > 0$. Find the measure of the set $\{x : f(x) \geq
 0\}$.

This post has the solution to the problem, but it does not match the answer provided in G. De Barra’s book, the answer in the book is $\frac{1}{\pi}(1-\log 2)$. Please tell me why are they different? Is the book wrong?

Could the answer in the book have a typo? Seems like the set should at least be greater than $ 1 - 1/\pi \approx 0.68$, and the book says the measure is $(1-\log 2)/\pi \approx 0.10$.

@TrevorNorton: yes, the book can have typo but it is a classical text that's why I'm confirming here.

The book is wrong. They probably meant to write $1 -\log 2 /\pi$.
